How to Set an Image for a Plugin in Shopware 6?
I'm trying to add an image for my custom plugin in Shopware 6, but I can’t seem to figure it out. I’m currently using Shopware version 6.6.6.1 with PHP 8.3.
I've looked through the documentation and some forum posts, but none of the solutions seem to work for this version. Specifically, I'm looking to add an image that will show up in the plugin manager, representing the plugin.
Has anyone successfully done this in the latest Shopware 6? If so, could you provide the steps or point out what I might be missing?
Thanks in advance!

Add the plugin.png file to the <plugin root>/src/Resources/config folder.

After this, the plugin image should appear in the admin panel.


Yes, it works. Don't know why it was such a mess to set my image to it. Thanks for help and such a stupid question
